# Delete the sources from a build after a build

Tags: tfsbuild

I have about 60 TFS builds that run on a bunch of machines that all build quite regularly.

We're constantly running out of space and its getting frustrating seeing 80 gigs of TFS sources on our build machines. Hell, we used 20 gigs of hard drive space over the weekend!

I'm looking for a way to delete the sources for the build immediately after the build. We really don't care all that much about speed, (we'd rather have builds actually complete) so downloading the sources again isn't an issue.

Its mainly the SOURCE directories that take up space, not the drop folders, so retention policies don't really do anything for us. We don't care about the output of the builds, just whether or not they build successfully or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this as an action to end of the Build Definition xaml

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, you can add a InvokeProcess activity. You can find a nice overview of your options at [my blog](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/?tag=/build+2010+customization)